# Where to store secret keys DJANGO

Tags: django, django-settings

For the life of me, I have been looking for this everywhere and have not found the answer. I hope I am not posting a duplicate.

It is advised everywhere that you should keep your secret keys in a separate file from your general settings.py. Also, that you should never commit your "secret.py" file that contains keys such as SECRET_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY and so on.

My question is: In your production server, you need to reference your secret keys, that means that your "secret.py" settings file, should live somewhere around the server right? If so, how do you protect your secret keys in production?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

See the [Django deployment docs for a discussion on this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/deployment/checklist/#secret-key).

There's quite a few options for production. The way I do it is by setting my sensitive data variables as environmental variables on the production environments. Then I retrieve the variables in the `settings.py` via `os.environ` like so:

```py
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

Another possible option is to copy in the `secret.py` file via your deploy script.

I'm sure there are also other specific options for different web servers.

Comment: For linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session . For my example above, you would add `export secret_KEY = 'ABABABABABDSFJKEWLSK'` in your `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` or `.profile` - depending on which exist.

Comment: I moved my secret key to .bash_profile and used os.environ.get, and it totally broke my site, even though `echo $SECRET_KEY` worked fine.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan That is not true. Only the user has read permission to it. Check for yourself with `stat /proc/$PID/environ`

Comment: @DanHoerst small note, on my machine removing the spaces surrounding the equal-sign was error free: `export secret_KEY='ABABABABABDSFJKEWLSK'`

Comment: @DanHoerst I tried this, but my secret key has a "#" in it, so when I saved it as an environment variable everything looks fine.  However, when I call it, it only returns everything before the "#".  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: gunicorn can't access environment variables, so why is this recommended?

Answer (score 125):

I wanted to add a new answer because, as a beginner, the previous accepted answer didn't make a lot of sense to me (it was only one part of the puzzle).

So here's how I store my keys both LOCALLY and in PRODUCTION (Heroku, and others).

**Note:** You really only have to do this if you plan on putting your project online. If it's just a local project, no need.

I also made a [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/bPR3Q0BFFzw) for people who prefer that format.

**1) Install python-dotenv to create a local project environment to store your secret key.**

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

**2) Create a `.env` file in your base directory (where `manage.py` is).**

```
YourDjangoProject
├───project
│   ├───__init__.py
│   ├───asgi.py
│   ├───settings.py
│   ├───urls.py
│   └───wsgi.py
├───.env
├───manage.py
└───db.sqlite3
```

If you have a Heroku project, it should look something like this:

```
YourDjangoProject
├───.git
├───project
│   ├───__init__.py
│   ├───asgi.py
│   ├───settings.py
│   ├───urls.py
│   └───wsgi.py
├───venv
├───.env
├───.gitignore
├───manage.py
├───Procfile
├───requirements.txt
└───runtime.txt
```

**3) Add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file.**

```
echo .env > .gitignore  # Or just open your .gitignore and type in .env
```

This is how you keep your secret key more secure because you don't upload your .env file to git or heroku (or wherever else).

**4) Add your SECRET_KEY from your settings.py file into the .env file like so (without quotes)**

```
**Inside of your .env file**
SECRET_KEY=qolwvjicds5p53gvod1pyrz*%2uykjw&a^&c4moab!w=&16ou7 # <- Example key, SECRET_KEY=yoursecretkey
```

**5) Inside of your settings.py file, add the following settings:**

```
import os
import dotenv # <- New

# Add .env variables anywhere before SECRET_KEY
dotenv_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")
if os.path.isfile(dotenv_file):
    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)

# UPDATE secret key
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] # Instead of your actual secret key
```

or, thanks to [@Ashkay Chandran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65411006/10415970) down below (please give him an upvote if you use it  I always use this):

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

And now your secret key is successfully stored locally.

**Update**: I found out you can also use the `config` method from the package `python-decouple` that seems to be a bit easier:

```
from decouple import config

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

Now you don't need to `import os` or use `dotenv` because it takes care of those parts for you AND will still use the .env file. I started using this in all of my projects.

**6) Add the SECRET_KEY environment variable on your host (such as Heroku).**

---

I work mostly with Heroku sites, so if you're wanting to use Heroku for a Django project, this part is for you.

This assumes that you already have a Heroku project setup and have Heroku CLI downloaded on your computer.

**You have 2 options:**

1. From Command Line / Terminal, you can enter the following command in your project's directory:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=yoursecretkey # Again, no quotes.
```

2. You can go to your Heroku dashboard, click on your app, go to your apps settings, and see the "Config Vars" section and click "Reveal Vars" or "Add Vars" and add your SECRET_KEY there.

Then, when you push your project to Heroku through git, it should be working properly without any issue.

and that's it!

This answer was targeted towards total beginners / intermediates to hopefully cut through any confusion (because it was definitely confusing for me).

Comment: thx for the config method from decouple. One hint: you need to install pip install python-decouple (And not pip install decouple)

Comment: Thanks for the `python-decouple` suggestion. That seems like the most precise way to do it. 
And also as @alexrogo mentioned, `pip install python-decouple` needs to be done first.

Answer (score 12):

You should store your settings in a modular way. By that I mean to spread your settings across multiple files.

For example, you can have `base_settings.py` to store all your base settings; `dev_settings.py` for your development server settings; and finally `prod_base_settings.py` for all production settings. All non-base settings files will import all the base settings and then only change whatever is necessary:

```
# base_settings.py
...

# dev_settings.py
from base_settings import *
DEBUG = TRUE
...

# prod_base_settings.py
from base_settings import *
DEBUG = FALSE
...
```

This approach allows you to have different settings from different setups. You can also commit all these files except then on the production server you can create the actual production settings file `prod_settings.py` where you will specify all the sensitive settings. This file should not be committed anywhere and its content kept secure:

```
# prod_settings.py
from prod_base_settings import *
SECRET_KEY = 'foo'
```

As for the file names you can use whatever filenames you feel are appropriate. Personally I actually create a Python package for the settings and then keep the various settings inside the package:

```
project/
  project/
    settings/
      __init__.py
      base.py
      dev.py
      ...
  app1/
    models.py
    ...
  app2/
    models.py
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I was looking at how to protect these keys.

Comment: By having all secret settings in the separate file is a way you protect it. It only does not protect in case server gets hacked where the file gets compromised. But in that case environment variables are only vulnerable, same as any other method I know of. There are methods for completely securing such information but all of them involve a third party storing the secure data and then your server can ask them for the info, but to make it secure, on each request, those services will send you notification where you have to validate the request so they are not completely automated.

Comment: How do you determine which set of settings to use. Is there an ìf``somewhere? In JS I check the host name (localhost or production server). That way I have a single code base and don't have to remember to make any manual changes when deploying.

Answer (score 8):

Storing secrets in the environment still places them in the environment; which can be exploited if an unauthorized user gains access to the environment. It is a trivial effort to list environment variables, and naming one `SECRET` makes is all the more helpful and obvious to <s>a bad actor</s> an unwanted user.

Yet secrets are necessary in production, so how to access them while minimizing attack surface? Encrypt each secret in a file with a tool like [git-secret](https://git-secret.io), then allow authorized users to read in the file, as mentioned in [django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/#secret-key). Then "tell" a non-root user the secret so it can be read-in during initialization.

(Alternatively, one could also use Hashicorp's Vault, and access the secrets stored in Vault via the [HVAC python](https://github.com/hvac/hvac) module.)

Once this non-root user is told, something like this is easy:

```
# Remember that './secret_key.txt' is encrypted until it's needed, and only read by a non-root user
with open('./secret_key.txt') as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()
```

This isn't perfect, and, yes, an attacker could enumerate variables and access it -- but it's very difficult to do so during run-time, and Django does a good job of protecting its keys from such a threat vector.

This is a much safer approach than storing secrets in the environment.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been trying to figure out how to hide SECRET_KEY for days, but everyone leaps straight to the "environment variable" solution without questioning it.  This post is the first acknowledgement I've found of the obvious danger of putting a secret into the environment where any process can access it.  I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 6):

I know it has been a long time, but I just opensourced a small Django app I am using to generate a new secret key if it does not exist yet. It is called [django-generate-secret-key](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-generate-secret-key).

```
pip install django-generate-secret-key
```

Then, when provisioning / deploying a new server running my Django project, I run the following command (from Ansible):

```
python manage.py generate_secret_key
```

It simply:

- checks if a secret key needs to be generated
- generates it in a `secretkey.txt` file (can be customized)

All you need then is to have in your settings file:

```
with open('/path/to/the/secretkey.txt') as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()
```

You can now benefit from a *fully automated* provisioning process *without having to store a static secret key* in your repository.

Comment: Hmm, with latest django (1.11) am getting: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/.../project/secretkey.txt'`

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan did you run `python manage.py generate_secret_key` first? If it did not create the file or if anything is wrong, then please open an issue here: https://github.com/MickaelBergem/django-generate-secret-key/issues/new so we can talk about this

Comment: what happens when you add a server?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of if/then logic you should use a tool designed for factoring out sensitive data.  I use YamJam https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yamjam/ .   It allows all the advantages of the os.environ method but is simpler -- you still have to set those environ variables, you'll need to put them in a script somewhere.  YamJam stores these config settings in a machine config store and also allows a project by project ability to override.

```
from YamJam import yamjam

variable = yamjam()['myproject']['variable']
```

Is the basic usage.  And like the os.environ method, it is not framework specific, you can use it with Django or any other app/framework.  I've tried them all, multiple settings.py files, brittle logic of if/then and environment wrangling.  In the end, I switched to yamjam and haven't regretted it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [zack-plauch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61437799/12167598)'s answer,
To get the path to the `.env` file, when using `python-dotenv` [module](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/), the `find_dotenv` method can be used,

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

The `find_dotenv()` looks for a "*.env*" file in the path, so it can be saved inside the same directory too,

Also, if a name is used for the `.env` file like "*django-config.env*", `load_dotenv(find_dotenv("django-config.env")`, will fetch and load that to host-machine environment variable mappings.

Comment: I added this to the main answer  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that noone has talked about [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
I usually create a `.env` file like this:

```
SECRET_KEY=blabla
OTHER_SECRET=blabla
```

This file should be added in `.gitignore`

You can checkin in git, an example file named `.env.example` just for others to know which env var they need. The content of `.env.example` file will look like this (just keys without any values)

```
SECRET_KEY=
OTHER_SECRETS=
```

Answer (score 0):

### Where to store `SECRET_KEY` DJANGO

> Store your django `SECRET_KEY` in an environmental variable or separate file, instead of directly encoding In your configuration module settings.py

`settings.py`

```
#from an environment variable
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

#from an file
with open('/etc/secret_key.txt') as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()
```

### How to generate Django `SECRET_KEY` manually:

```
$ python -c "from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key; print(get_random_secret_key())"
```

`7^t+3on^bca+t7@)w%2pedaf0m&$_gnne#^s4zk3a%4uu5ly86`

```
import string
import secrets

c = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

secret_key = ''.join(secrets.choice(c) for i in range(67))

print(secret_key)
```

`df&)ok{ZL^6Up$\y2*">LqHx:D,_f_of#P,~}n&\zs*:y{OTU4CueQNrMz1UH*mhocD`

*Make sure the key used in production is not used elsewhere and avoid sending it to source control.*

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternatives to anyone skittish to store secrets in environment variables (see e.g., [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129631/linux-securing-environment-variables)):

#### 1. [SOPS](https://github.com/mozilla/sops)

0. Set up SOPS (see its [README](https://github.com/mozilla/sops/blob/master/README.rst)).
1. Put your secrets in one of the supported configuration file format (such as YAML, JSON, ENV, INI and BINARY formats).
2. Encrypt it.

   In my case, I used the following command:

   ```
   sops --encrypt --azure-kv  <endpoint_url> secrets.json > secrets.sops.json
   ```
3. Add the value-encrypted file to source control (in the case above, `secrets.json`), and either delete the original or back it up somewhere secure.
4. In `settings.py`, add the following (or similar) to load the secrets.

   For example:

   ```py
   import json
   import subprocess

   decrypted = subprocess.run(["sops", "--decrypt", "secrets.sops.json"], capture_output=True)
   config = json.loads(decrypted.stdout)
   ```
5. Add secrets wherever needed.

   For example:

   ```py
   SECRET_KEY = config['SECRET_KEY']
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = config['ALLOWED_HOSTS'] + ['192.168.64.4']
   DATABASES = config['DATABASES']
   ```

   where `DATABASE` looks like this in my JSON file:

   ```json
   { ... ,
     "DATABASES": {
       "default": {
         "ENGINE": "ENC[AES256_GCM,data:...,iv:.../pc=,tag:...,type:str]",
         "NAME": "ENC[AES256_GCM,data:...,iv:.../pc=,tag:...,type:str]",
         "USER": "ENC[AES256_GCM,data:...,iv:.../pc=,tag:...,type:str]",
         "PASSWORD": "ENC[AES256_GCM,data:...,iv:.../pc=,tag:...,type:str]",
         "HOST": "ENC[AES256_GCM,data:...,iv:.../pc=,tag:...,type:str]",
         "PORT": "ENC[AES256_GCM,data:...,iv:.../pc=,tag:...,type:str]"
       }   
     },  
     ...
   }
   ```

#### [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/)

0. Install [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/).
1. Create a KeePass database for the project.

   This [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/KeePass/comments/10ahzkm/keepass_vs_keepassxc_worried_about_security/) is a great security settings best practices reference.
2. Create a new entry, and add `settings.py` as attachment.
3. Delete `settings.py` from the repo (or back it up securely somewhere else), and add to `.gitignore` (if using Git, that is).
4. Add the newly created KeePass database to the repo (e.g., `settings.kdbx`).
5. Extract `settings.py` from the database whenever needed:

   ```
                                   <--database-> <----entry-----> <attachment> 
   keepassxc-cli attachment-export settings.kdbx project_settings settings.py --stdout
   ```

---

#### The combination of SOPS and KeePassXC

The SOPS route is more intimidating, but I like that I can keep `settings.py` and the secrets file in the repo, and only the actual secrets are "redacted".

I actually use them together:

1. A KeePass database holds a shell script as attachment that exports the environment variables necessary to use the dedicated Azure service principal.

   The following command will extract the attachment and run the script in one go in Bash:

   ```
   source <(keepassxc-cli attachment-export <db> <entry> export.sh --stdout)
   ```
2. The development environment is set up via a [`shell.nix` script](https://github.com/society-for-the-blind/slate-2/blob/main/dev_shell.nix) that sets up a PostgreSQL instance and the database using the secrets from the JSON:

   ```
   d () { sops --decrypt secrets/lynx_settings.sops.json | \
            jq -r ".[\"DATABASES\"][\"default\"][\"$1\"]"; \
   }

   createdb $(d "NAME") --host=$PGDATA --port=$(d "PORT")

     psql \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
       --host=$PGDATA \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
       --username=$(whoami) \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       --dbname=$(d "NAME")  \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
       --command="CREATE ROLE $(d 'USER') WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '$(d 'PASSWORD')'
   ```
3. `settings.py` is set up as described above so any Django command will work as expected.