# Python secrets file ( Where to store api tokens )

Tags: python, authentication

What is the recommended pythonic way to store oauth tokens?

Currently I am storing them directly in my python script, but should they be in a different file like a .secrets file and then imported into the script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing the secrets (passwords) in a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501403/storing-the-secrets-passwords-in-a-separate-file)