# which gitignore file shall i use when uploading a django project which contain a secret key?

Tags: python, django, github, gitignore

I am new to GitHub:  I have uploaded a django project without a `.gitignore` file and GitHub Community banned my account.

That is why I need to know how to use a `.gitignore` file as well as adding a license.

Comment: We answer one question per question only. Make sure it's specific! We cant explain everything here. For a full overview consult the documentation, any tutorial or book.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate your django project locally, initialize a new local git repository in init (`git init .`), and, *before* doing any `git add`/`git commit`, add:

- your `.gitignore` (you can copy the [Django one](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/django))
- your `LICENSE` file ([chose one of those](https://choosealicense.com/))

Add and commit locally.

Then create a new GitHub account, a new *empty* GitHub repository.

Go back to your local repository and:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add origin https://github.com/<NewAccount>/<newRepo>
git push -u origin master
```

You can then see "[Where to store secret keys DJANGO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61437799/6309)" for managing your secret key.