# How do I get around ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dot env

Tags: django, unit-testing

I am doing the official django tutorial polls app on part 5 which is about testing in django. As a part of the instructions I am supposed to go into my models.py file and run the python manage.py shell command to activate a shell terminal. From there I am supposed to run a series of commands to import things for my test.

Link to material: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial05/

The commands I need to run are:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> from polls.models import Question
>>> # create a Question instance with pub_date 30 days in the future
>>> future_question = Question(pub_date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30))
>>> # was it published recently?
>>> future_question.was_published_recently()
True
```

I run the import datetime, and from django.utils import timezone and there are no issues.
Once I get to from polls.models import Question I am hit with an error message no modulenotfounderror" no module named dot env.

[image]

I have tried looking at stack overflow articles and they suggested installing it via pip. So I exited my shell command and tried installing dotenv with pip. When I do so I get the following error message shown in the screenshot. [image]

I looked at this stack overflow article python modulenotfounderror and ran the
pip install python-dotenv command and got this error when attempting:

I have since uninstalled that command hoping to reset back to what I had when I started the problem.

I have posted this question to django forums and discord to see if I can get an answer.

I have searched on youtube to see if I can get around this.

My specific question would be how do I get this django test to work. I believe it has to do with this dotenv error.

Do you think since its a tutorial I could just update the code to what it is saying in the instructions and move on?

```
from pathlib import Path
import os 
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209978/where-to-store-secret-keys-django either this or remove it
# I did option one and it worked! 

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin', 
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mysite_database',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

## Default primary key field type

## https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

Comment: did these help you : 1. [This error originates from a subprocess...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009659/message-note-this-error-originates-from-a-subprocess-and-is-likely-not-a-prob) 2. [subprocess-exited-with-error](https://sebhastian.com/python-error-subprocess-exited-with-error/)

Comment: Your screenshot shows `pip install dotenv`, but then you say you installed it with `pip install python-dotenv`.  I'm not sure, but I think the `pip install python-dotenv` is the one that you should use.

Comment: I have managed to run pip install python-dotenv and not I get a new error! which I consider progress! :)

it says KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'.

I wonder what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the original question is to run `pip install python-dotenv` ([PyPI link](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)) as opposed to `pip install dotenv`, a package that hasn't been updated since 2018, as seen in the [Github](https://github.com/pedroburon/dotenv) link.

Now for the `KeyError` you ran into.

`KeyError` means it didn't find the key `SECRET_KEY`, which from your screenshots is probably because there is no **.env** file that I can see.  Just create a file called **.env** (NOTE, it must be called **.env** with a **.** and not just **env**), and this is where you will store secret keys (which hopefully you won't post on StackOverflow).  Something like this:

```
# .env

SECRET_KEY=aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ123456789
DATABASE_PASSWORD=aVeryStrongDatabsePassword
ANOTHER_KEY=ujhgasdhfcdahfda123794123472314723judh

# Any other variables you need to keep secret
```

You can easily generate long, secure passwords and keys using [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_urlsafe).

Finally, please copy and paste code.  Do not use screenshots for this.  Checkout [why should I not use screenshots?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)  And checkout this link, [5 Ways to Embed Code in StackOverflow](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/5-ways-to-embed-code-in-stack-overflow-8d9f38edf02c) if you're not sure how.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and I have saved the link for not using screenshots next to the article for how to ask a better questions on stackoverflow as well as 5 ways to embed code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that when I tried setting up my secret_key via Zach Plauchè's answer I used one of the other techniques the others set up. When I ran purely off of his method that he first mentioned it worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61437799/17598401

it seems i need to learn more about environment variables and secret key set ups. for the time being I am satisfied with the workaround and will continue through the polls app tutorial.