# Set an environment variable (password) in a way its value is not saved to the bash history

Tags: bash

When I login to MySQL as root I usually set MROOTPASS environment variable

```
export MROOTPASS=my-secret-password
```

and then do

```
mysql -u root -p$MROOTPASS
```

this eliminates the need to reenter the password each time I connect to MySQL as root, but obviously it is insecure because the password is saved to the bash history file. Is it possible to prevent the password from being saved?

Comment: *Store your password in an option file.* See: [6.1.2.1 End-User Guidelines for Password Security](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html)

Comment: If you put some whitespace at the start of the command, that will prevent it from entering your history: "[space]export ..." -- the [HISTCONTROL variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTCONTROL) controls this.

Comment: Irrelevant, but there's no need to export `MROOTPASS` if you are using it in the same shell session where you define it.

Comment: It's more the bash history. From @Cyrus's link: "[Using -p] is convenient but insecure. On some systems, your password becomes visible to system status programs such as ps that may be invoked by other users to display command lines. MySQL clients typically overwrite the command-line password argument with zeros during their initialization sequence. However, there is still a brief interval during which the value is visible. Also, on some systems this overwriting strategy is ineffective and the password remains visible to ps."

Comment: Use a `/root/.my.cnf` where for each block, e.g. `[mysqladmin]`, `[mysql]`, `[mysqldump]`, etc... you can provide the `password = xxxx` and `user = xxxx` to allow access without needing to provide a user or password on the command line. See [MySQL Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html) -- which is the same for MariaDB.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could just enter the variable using

```
read -s -p "Enter password:" MROOTPASS
```

this way it also wouldn't appear anywhere without having to save it in a file. Instead you just have to enter it once. The -s option tells read not to echo the typed characters, so nobody can look it up while you type it.

Edit: long time after this answer was accepted some people stated, that this doesn't define system variables but shell variables. If you need your variable to be visible in a subshell, you just need to export the variable by adding the following line below the read statement (bash):

```
export MROOTPASS
```

---

Man pages for the `read` built-in command in different shells:

- [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read)
- [fish](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/read.html)
- [zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#:%7E:text=read%20%5B%20%2DrszpqAclneE,%5D%20%5D%20%5B%20name%20...%20%5D)
- dash - has `read` built-in, but does not support this use case

Comment: this command defines **shell** variable, not **environmental** one as OP asked, so if your command/script/program waits for env var it won't get one, just try to print `env | grep MROOTPASS` and you'll see nothing

Comment: is this an environment variable or a shell variable.

Comment: @baxx: this was not realy the question since, as you can see, the password is passed by subsituting the variable back. I think, that's why the poster accepted this solution and it is a bit unfair to downvote my post, as you both obviously did!

Comment: @vladkras: what i wrote to baxx's comment, applies to your comment/downvote as well. The point is, that if the variable would be required to be visible in the subshell, then an easy extra `export MYROOTPASS` below the read, would do the trick.

Answer (score 15):

```
$ read -rs PASSWORD
$ export PASSWORD
```